# Get the number after a slash

Tags: php, regex

I have the following text:

```
Page 1/50
```

How would I get just the number after the slash (50) and put it into a variable using PHP? What method do I use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using PHP 5.4 or higher you can use array dereferncing to do this as a one liner:

```
echo explode('/', 'Page 1/50')[1];
```

If you're using an older version of PHP, this should do the same thing:

```
list(, $number) = explode('/', 'Page 1/50');
echo $number;
```

Comment: If you're using an older version of php which doesn't support array dereferencing you could use `echo end(explode('/', 'Page 1/50'))`

Comment: @billyonecan I'm pretty sure that would result in a notice.

Answer (score 0):

```
$value = end(explode('/', $text));
```

Comment: Really it does not. Enable error reporting and try running it again.

Comment: @PeeHaa, what exceptions does this produce? I've used it before without any problems.

Comment: @DustinFain You should really enable error reporting when developing: http://3v4l.org/gtbsd

Answer (score 0):

If this is always your pattern, you can try:

```
$currPage;
$totalPages;
sscanf('Page 1/50', 'Page %d/%d', $currPage, $totalPages);

var_dump($currPage, $totalPages);
```